Reflection: How to get private field's value from kotlin companion object?
I want to have an extension that would allow me to get value of private field dataMap from companion object for unit tests.
class with companion object:
@Service
class BroadcastServiceImpl {
    companion object : KLogging() {
        private val dataMap: MutableMap<String, MutableSet<UserData>> = mutableMapOf()
    }
}

I wrote such a method using reflection. But it has a compilation error. And I can’t even imagine how to solve it
private fun BroadcastServiceImpl.getDataMap(): Map<String, Set<UserData>> {
    return javaClass.getDeclaredField("dataMap").let {
        it.isAccessible = true
        val value = it.get(this)
        return@let value;
    }
}

compilation error:
Type mismatch.
Required:
Map<String, Set<UserData>>
Found:
Any!


When attempting to use reflection always "dump" list of fields with their type first so you have basic understanding of what can you do. Also companions are separate classes alltogether so you should be getting java class of BroadcastServiceImpl.Companion instead.

it helped me to get field value
val field = BroadcastServiceImpl::class.java.getDeclaredField("dataMap")
field.isAccessible = true
return field.get(null) as (HashMap<String, Set<UserData>>)

